# How to perform a three-way PCA in R

Tags: multidimensional-array, pca, n-way

I would like to perform a three-way principal component analysis in R, and though I have found a few articles explaining how it works and how to interpret results, I cannot find any useful guides online on how to do it in R.

My data consists of 230 samples, 250,000 variables and 50 annotations. Usually people just do a standard PCA using only one annotation on the following type of data:

Standard data:

```
        var1 var2 var3 var4
Sample1  1/1  0/0  1/1  1/0
Sample2  1/0  1/1  1/1  1/0
Sample3  0/0  1/1  1/1  1/1
Sample4  0/0  0/0  1/1  0/0
Sample5  1/0  1/0  0/0  1/1
```

However, I would like to implement all annotation information into the analysis, such that I use all 50 matrices combindly for the analysis. In this way a combination of annotations may explain more of the variance between samples than a single annotation does alone, e.g. annotation 1 and 4 together explain more variance that annotation 1 alone.

Annotation 1:

```
         var1 var2 var3 var4
Sample1  1/1  0/0  1/1  1/0
Sample2  1/0  1/1  1/1  1/0
Sample3  0/0  1/1  1/1  1/1
Sample4  0/0  0/0  1/1  0/0
Sample5  1/0  1/0  0/0  1/1
```

Annotation 2:

```
         var1      var2      var3  var4
Sample1  missense  none      STOP  synonymous
Sample2  missense  missense  STOP  synonymous
Sample3  none      missense  STOP  synonymous
Sample4  none      none      STOP  none
Sample5  missense  missense  none  synonymous
```

Annotation 3:

```
         var1  var2   var3  var4
Sample1  0.30   0.00  0.01  0.04
Sample2  0.30  -0.24  0.01  0.04
Sample3  0.00  -0.24  0.01  0.04
Sample4  0.00  -0.24  0.01  0.00
Sample5  0.30  -0.24  0.00  0.04
```

Annotation 4:

```
         var1  var2  var3  var4
Sample1  CTCF  NONE  NONE  MAX
Sample2  CTCF  NONE  NONE  MAX
Sample3  NONE  NONE  NONE  MAX
Sample4  NONE  NONE  NONE  NONE
Sample5  CTCF  NONE  NONE  MAX
```

From what I have found there are three packages that can do the Tucker 3-way PCA: ThreeWay, PTAk and rTensor. I have tried to run ThreeWay, but the data structure that they use seems very ugly to work with. Maybe I could make this work, but the example in the ThreeWay article also generated an error, so I would prefer another package:

ThreeWay data structure:

```
         var1_anno1    var1_anno2    var1_anno3   var2_anno1    var2_anno2
Sample1  1/1           missense      0.30         0/0           missense
Sample2  1/0           missense      0.30         1/1           missense
Sample3  0/0           none          0.30         1/1           missense
Sample4  0/0           none          0.30         0/0           none
Sample5  1/0           missense      0.30         1/0           missense
```

The PTAk packages requires:
"a tensor (as an array) of order k, if non-identity metrics are used X is a list with data as the array and met a list of metrics"

It is not clear to me what this means. I tried to look into the tensor packages of how to generate a tensor, but their example is very convoluted as they do tons of multiplications on various tensors, rather than explain the basics of how to create a tensor form ones data.

I would appreciate both comments on weaknesses of this approach and on how to create tensors, and how to analyse them using any of the packages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the **PTAk** package for running the analysis.

To build the tensors, I used the two packages **tensor** and **abind**.

I built the tensors (aka Multi-way Arrays) by creating a vector from a matrix, and then re-defining its dimensions in three dimensions. The function `abind()` was then used to merge the arrays from each individual into the final three-dimensional tensor.

```
for (i in 1:length(list_of_sample_matrices)) {  

    # Converting matrix into single sample tensor
    single_sample_tensor <- array(as.vector(list_of_sample_matrices[i])), c(250000, 50, 1))
    
    # Creating all sample tensor
    if (i == 1) {
        all_sample_tensor <- single_sample_tensor
    }

    # Adding a single sample tensor at the time to the all sample tensor
    if (i > 1) {
        all_sample_tensor <- abind(all_sample_tensor, single_sample_tensor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all functions `PTAk()`, `FCAk()`, `PCAn()` and `CANDPARA()` (for `CANDECOMP` or `PARAFAC`) the data input is an array generated more likely from the function `array()`.

Preparing the data read by `array()`, you need to remember there is (like for `matrix()`, for rows and columns) an order of indices the first running faster than the next etc...

So, using `as.vector()`, `cbind()`, `rbind()`, and all other data manipulation can prepare the data to be read by `array()`, and then possibly also using `abind()` (package abind) to combine some arrays.

Some examples are given in the [JSS paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v034i10)

e.g. `abind(x1,x2,x3,x4,...xp,along=3)` is indeed quite convenient to create a 3-way array n x q x p from the series of  p matrices x1,x2, ... ,xp of dimensions n x q.